# Как из статической функции обратиться к list

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте)
У меня такая проблема, есть статическая (static) функция, указатель на которую уходит в другой класс и там же вызывается (callback).В эту функцию приходят картинки в виде     структуры с 3-мя char* и при вызове этой ф-ции мне эту картинку надо положить в list.
Но из этой функции я не могу вызвать функции list, такие как push_back() и т.д
Visual Studio говорит что  см. картинку. 
[image]
Заранее спасибо

Код:

```
".h"  
public:
static void func (BMPImage* frame);  
std::list <BMPImage*> images;
```

".cpp"

```
void Gallery::func(BMPImage* frame){

 //вот тут не "видит" 

}
```

Comment: header подключен в cpp файле?

Comment: да конечно

Comment: да( но мне нельзя делать list статичным

Comment: Либо делаете поле статичным, либо убираете статик у метода, либо необходимо передавать в этот метод экземпляр класса.

Comment: а как тогда угадывать статическому классу, куда именно записывать?

Comment: @KoVadim я понимаю что так делать нельзя, ну в теории.
Но я не могу сделать list статичным, и иного выхода не вижу

Comment: если callback не статичный то вылетает ощибка :
    
error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'void (__thiscall Gallery::* )(BMPImage *)' to 'DSE::fCallback'

Comment: Зачем вам вообще статичный коллбэк? Есть же method pointers.

Вот, [пример][1] накидал.

А вообще, для колбэков отлично подходят интерфейсы. Почему бы не использовать их вместо указателей на функции/методы?

  [1]: http://ideone.com/GCvt1U

Comment: @falstaf: указатели на метод прекрасно оборачиваются в `std::function`.

Comment: @VladD: возможно, довольно-таки давно отошёл от плюсов. Но разве std::function не в C++11 появился?

Answer (score 1):

[@falstaf](/users/5517/falstaf), не надо изобретать велосипеды. `{boost,std}::bind(&ClassName::MethodName, this)` и все.

Answer (score 0):

У вас `func` — это статическая функция в классе `Gallery`, а `images` — это член класса. Статические функции по своему определению не имеют доступа к членам класса, поскольку *выполняются в отрыве от конкретного экземпляра объекта.*

В C++03 можно использовать [`boost::function.`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/function.html) Собственно, `std::function` — это тот же `boost::function,` но перекочевавший в Standard Library.